# Travis-ci fails every single build and won't 'refresh' .travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci

I've tried to run travis to check my PHP code, to see how bad my code will run on other PHP versions.

But, it seems that I have 2 issues.

Travis finds the .travis.yml file, but won't respect it in any way.
Expect when I change it, then it runs the specified PHP versions.

When it runs, it completely ignores the `script:` bit.

Here's my `.travis.yml` file:

```
# see http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/php/ for more hints
language: php

php:
  - 4.4
  - 5.2
  - 5.3
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - hhvm

script: phpunit --ignore-configuration --coverage-text
```

On line 87 of my log, I have this:

```
$ phpunit
```

Which looks to me to be the command to run.

Then, on line 166, I have this:

```
The command "phpunit" exited with 2.
```

What am I doing wrong?
The documentation is a big nope to me: Can't understand anything, too over-complicated, badly explained, badly organized.

**I'M STUCK**

Please, help me before I lose my sanity!

Comment: Can you provide a link to your travis build?

Comment: @Odi I got it working now. Travis is actually very badly done in this aspect. After about 5 hours looking into the website, I've found out that I need to go to the build history and manually select which build to test. Because this won't "recognize" the latest build, being impossible to test it properly without going this way around. And when I test the build, I end up waiting around 40 minutes before all the builds are done (if I don't test one build, it seems to be testing every single build that wasn't tested).